# Kafka streams on spring, trouble with exactly once ACL: TransactionalIdAuthorizationException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I'm having trouble to connect to a topic on Confluent cloud from a springboot kafka-streams application, the connection failing with a single error line 
`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TransactionalIdAuthorizationException: Transactional Id authorization failed.`

I believe this is because the topic is configured to allow transactions with a specified transactial-id (https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html#enabling-authorization-for-idempotent-and-transactional-apis). My service being a streaming application, generates a transactional-id in each StreamThread (create producer method in https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.1/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java) which is defined as `applicationId + "-" + taskId` and  this does not match the one defined on topic ACL.

Is this a correct, and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Is there some reason you added the [tag:spring-kafka] tag? Spring simply uses the underlying kafka-clients and kafka-streams library so this is out of its control.

Comment: Noted, editing to remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use wildcard ACLs by only specifying the prefix, ie, `<application.id>-` for the corresponding ACL, using `--resource-pattern-type prefixed`

Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/security.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @matthias-j-sax. So an explicit transaction-id prefix is not supported on the streaming client? Transaction prefix has to always be the application id for this it work or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct: `transaction.id` cannot be configured by the user, but Kafka Streams configures it automatically using the `application.id` as prefix.